# How to interpret my path analysis with multiple mediation? Help with error covariance

Tags: structural-equation-modeling

I need help interpreting my path analysis. I already reached the best fitting model but I am having difficulty interpreting. All the paths are significant and both direct, indirect and total effects are significant as well. To explain my model, I have 3 exogenous variables and 2 mediators, and 1 outcome variable. Between both mediators I have a significant error covariance that I am struggling to interpret. In addition, one of my mediators has a significant direct effect to the outcome variable and the other one does not. I am struggling to interpret the meaning of the indirect paths that flow through variable 6.
Thank you for the time spent reading, and if you could help I would be very much appreciate it.

[image: best model]

Answer (score 0):

> Between both mediators I have a significant error covariance that I am struggling to interpret

Residual correlations are partial correlations, controlling for whatever predictors' variance has been partialed out.  I agree yours is difficult to interpret because you are controlling for different variables:

- Variable 5 is regressed on 1 and 3
- Variable 6 is regressed on 2 and 3

So the residual correlation is how strongly Variables 5 and 6 are linearly related when holding 1 & 3 (but not 2) constant for Variable 5, and holding 2 & 3 (but not 1) constant for Variable 6.

If you would like a clearer interpretation, perhaps regress both on all 3 predictors.  Data-driven trimming of nonsignificant paths based on *p* values is not recommended.

> I am struggling to interpret the meaning of the indirect paths that flow through variable 6

There is no such indirect effect in your model because you fixed the effect of Variable 6 on 7 to zero.  Because Variable 6's residuals are correlated with Variable 5's, and 5 affects 7, your model still allows Variables 6 and 7 to be correlated, but your model says that the relationship is spurious, not causal.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. I understand what you meant by the partial correlation. I forgot to say that theoretically, the error covariance between 5 and 6 make sense so I need to leave it in the model. So I can't say there are indirect effects that flow through variable 6. But it is correct to say that a higher score in variable 3, leads through a higher score on variable 6 and because of the error covariance and because of factors not included in the model, that it will lead to a higher use of 5 and so to a higher use of 7? Or should I not make that assumption?

Comment: The path you describe is part of the decomposition of the covariance between variables 5 and 7, but it is not part of the decomposed effect (regression slope).  This book's first chapter discusses path-tracing rules, which might help: https://www.isical.ac.in/~arnabc/discrete/loehlin.pdf